# Why isn't data available via Azure's API

Tags: azure, api

Why is it that the network data and security group data (both available on the console) cannot be retrieved with the calling API, but can be retrieved with the resource group data

I hope to get my network data and security group data through API

Answer (score 0):

I tested the `Virtual Networks - Get` API in official [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/networksecuritygroups/get). And it works fine. I could get the vnet details with postman.

[image]

I suggest you try to use the **Try It** in the site , after you login in it will generate the Authorization token.
[image]

If you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: I'm sorry to reply you so late.Today, I tried your method and acquired Network data through Try it.
But I write through their own procedures, access to the data is still empty.
Before that, my program could get data with other accounts, and I don't understand why.
The data I get through the program is as follows: {"value":[]}